# How to combine multiple saved/existing plots (not ggplot) in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a loop that generates a plot (not ggplot) in each run. I have saved them individually (p1, p2, p3, p4 ...) but not able to combine them into one final plot. I know grid.arrange can do this perfectly but that only applies to ggplot.

I have tried

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

p1

p2

p3

p4

but they still show up as individual plot.

Comment: try the `cowplot` package

Comment: I sugget you provide the code that is used to generate the plots. This would be helpful to help you find a solution.

Comment: cowplot works for my purpose.